# Not able to import facebook friend list via django-easy-friends app

Tags: django, facebook

I am trying to import facebook friendlist for a user using django-easy-friends app.

In facebook app setting i have

```
Site URL:http://localhost:8000/friends/suggestions/suggested_friends/
```

I am getting following error when i try to import friend list.

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs     is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Following is the facebook import class in importers.py in (friends/contrib/suggestions/backends )

```
class FacebookImporter(BaseImporter):

def get_contacts(self, credentials):
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(credentials["xxx"])
    friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
    for friend in friends["data"]:
        yield {
            "name": friend["name"],
            "email": "",
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should not rely on these apps and create one on your own for your particular needs.

Comment: ya i am now creating a api for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you haven't registered the URL on Facebook APP,

Solution: Register the URL on your Facebook APP settings page under the website tab.